# Slow Performance in UPDATE Query Based on SELECT TOP 1

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-performance

I am trying to improve the performance of a query which takes long to run and would appreciate any pointers on what I need to do differently to get the performance to reasonable.  (Index and estimated execution plan info is included below.)

The table being updated, table1, has under 1000 records, but the table being queried has something in the range of 100 million. What's odd is that I use nearly the same query for oldest vs. most recent values, yet the query for the most recent value comes back in two seconds.  This is the query for the oldest value; it takes over two minutes to run:

```
UPDATE table1
SET firstVal = (
                    SELECT TOP 1 val 
                    FROM table2 
                    WHERE table1.ID = ID
                    AND valID = 123
                    ORDER BY entryDate
                    )
```

Query for the most recent, returns in two seconds:

```
UPDATE table1
SET lastVal = (
                    SELECT TOP 1 val 
                    FROM table2  
                    WHERE table1.ID = ID
                    AND valID = 123
                    ORDER BY entryDate DESC
                    )
```

Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [table2_IX9] ON [dbo].[table2]
(
    [valID] ASC,
    [entryDate] ASC,
    [ID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [val]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [AB]
GO
```

Index Seek (NonClustered) Cost: 68%
Top Cost: 29%

Can this query be phrased in a better way to optimize?  Is there something I need to different on the index side?  Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: do you have any NULL value in `entryDate` ?

Comment: Great question! but no

Comment: I may be wrong here, but try and change the index from `valID, entryDate, ID` to `valId, ID, entryDate` (or add in a second index) - I'd assume you'd want the 2 columns in the `where` clause ahead of the one of the `order by` in your index, otherwise, your search can't use the index exactly as-is... But I am quite the SQL newbie...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look into it but it will take a while for me to actually see if this does the trick since my test environment isn't quite so populated and I'll have to do a change control for production environment

Comment: John's comment is correct on the indexing

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for comments, but this may work quicker:

```
UPDATE T1
SET firstVal = T2.val
FROM Table1 T1
     --This might need to be an OUTER APPLY, but impossible to tell from your post
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ca.val
                  FROM Table2 ca
                  WHERE ca.ID = T1.ID
                    AND ca.valID = 123
                  ORDER BY ca.entryDate) T2;
```

The way you have it may mean that the query is run separately for each row, not as a dataset. This way will force the query to run as a dataset.

Comment: Thanks!  I believe you are correct.  Will try your idea right now

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  Unfortunately, estimated execution plan and actually running it show that this query is basically the same as my previous version :(

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

```
SELECT ID, val, entryDate
INTO #tmpT2
FROM table2 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table1)
AND valID = 123
```

And then with minor tweaks, swap out #tmpT2 for table2 in the original query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET firstVal = (
                    SELECT TOP 1 val 
                    FROM #tmpT2 
                    WHERE table1.ID = ID
                    ORDER BY entryDate
                    )
```

Why: Just realized that with the indexing in place looking exactly like it seemed it should, and table1 being so small, I could try to simply use a temp table and retrieve all IDs, vals and entryDates for the valID = 123 into the temp table.  This step took one second, and using the original query was instantaneous.  Thanks for taking the time to think this problem through and offer ideas!